# Change the name of flowfile in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I  want to change name my flowfile in updateAtrribute processor i have tried this

```
${filename:replace("Info"):append('.'):append(${fromDate})}
```

but it fails exception tells me that i have invalid expression what should i do?

Comment: Please include the full error in your post.

Comment: Invalid Expression:${filename:replace("Info"):append('.'):append(${fromDate})} due to unexpected token') ar line1, column 25

Comment: This is not a good question. Please specify what is your end-goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this way it works :

```
${filename:replace(${filename},"Info"):append(${fromDate})}
```